# How to deduce the ODE from difference equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, taylor-expansion, differential, numerical-calculus

Consider a difference equation
$$
x(t+h)=x(t)+hf(t)+\frac{h^2}{2}g(t),
$$
where $h$ is infinitesimal, $f,g$ are given functions of time.
Let $h\to0$, we get
$$
x'(t)=f(t).
$$
But if I substitute Taylor expansion into L.H.S., I get
$$
x'(t)=f(t),\quad x''(t)=g(t),
$$
so
$$
f'(t)=g(t).
$$
But $f,g$ are arbitrary functions. What's wrong?

Comment: The issue is that you stopped at the second term in the Taylor expansion.

Comment: Your first equation is quite possible for fixed $h$. As soon as you demand that the recursion equation is valid for variable $h$ with the same function $x$, you get contradictions as described that only resolve if $g=f'$.